# After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 Unicode Fallback does not work in inkscape

Tags: xubuntu, fonts, unicode, inkscape

I upgraded to 14.04 and opened a SVG with amharic letters. The letters are አዲስ and I use the font DejaVu sans. Now after the upgrade, the characters are displayed wrongly. If I copy from Inkscape and paste to gedit it is displayed correct in gedit

[image: Screenshot]

**edit** It is Amharic alphabet. The line around the letters does not belong to them, it is a rounded rectangle.

Comment: Could you show us what they are meant to look like? Is it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amharic_language#Alphabet?

Comment: Yes it is the Amharic language.

Comment: Do you have `fonts-droid` installed? I was having a similar problem with Japanese characters in inkscape/chrome on 14.04 (worked fine on previous ubuntu versions), and the workaround here http://superuser.com/a/716226 for chrome fixed inkscape for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me - inspired by Jason Conti's comment.

```
myuser@myhost:/etc/fonts/conf.d $ sudo rm *droid*
myuser@myhost:/etc/fonts/conf.d $ sudo fc-cache -f -r
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fileformat](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1235/index.htm) says that [the only fonts that support it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1235/fontsupport.htm) are

```
Code2000
FreeSerif
GNU Unifont
LastResort
Unicode BMP Fallback SIL.
```

(although only the first 2 look like it)

Inkscape has the font `FreeSerif`, and it displays correctly with that.

See [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4MquRqcDUx1Ry1McnphVUx3cUU/edit?usp=sharing) for an example.

Comment: The point is that before the upgrade it was working - so I think there was some automatic fallback which seems to not work now anymore.

Comment: Also it does not display properly with FreeSerif. OpenOffice seems to fallback properly to a font with this code.